# Connection timeout between TeamCity and Github

Tags: github, ssh, teamcity

We recently moved to Github and we have been trying to sort out the ssh connection between TeamCity and Github but we've hit a wall at connection timeouts when testing the connection on TeamCity.

```
List remote refs failed: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

[image]

We have added the ssh keys on both TeamCity and Github. Note the 'Never used' on the Github key

[image]

The TeamCity authentication Settings:
[image]

How do I get the ssh connection to work?

Comment: Connection timeouts generally suggest that you have a firewall blocking connections from the client to the server.

Comment: Yeah we tried to use telnet on port 22 and got very weird results. We eventually just used the config file with a custom port of 443 and everything is ok now :/

Answer (score 1):

> we tried to use telnet on port 22 and got very weird results. We eventually just used the config file with a custom port of 443 and everything is ok now

If this is in a company environment, I can confirm any [egress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egress_filtering) traffic on port 22 would be blocked by default.

You can check it on your own workstation, with `ssh -Tv -i /path/to/private/key git@github.com`.
If you don't see a "welcome" message, SSH is blocked.